# How can a website manage it's currently open tabs inside a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, node.js, browser

This code will open a link in a new tab:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">...</a>
```

But I'd like that link to open:

1. In a new tab, if there's no tab currently open displaying "mymusicstudioapp.com"
2. Inside a currently existing tab "mymusicstudioapp.com" if it's already open in the user's browser.

**I have control on how links are structured** since they will be generated from mymusicstudioapp.com before they are shared throughout various sources across the web.

Below I analyze the kind of behavior I'm trying to achieve in detail:
[image]
I can't make the studio as a desktop app because:

1. Music compositions should be links that are easier to share instead of files.
2. If I implement a custom url in the browser like "mymusicstudioapp: 8jiS9" the browser will keep asking the user to switch apps everytime he opens a new music composition.

**Did you mean to switch apps?**

"Microsoft Edge" is trying to open "MyMusicStudioApp".

[YES]   [NO]

Comment: You cannot force new windows to open in tabs; that's under user control. You can use a name in your links with the `target` attribute instead of always asking for a new window/tab with "_blank".

Comment: I can generate any kind of link but I don't have control on the HTML code. Most links will be like "mymusicstudioapp.com/9sGkd".

Comment: If you can't control what the `<a>` tags look like, then you can't do what you ask.

Comment: This only means I should ditch the "tabs inside the studio" idea altogether. Thanks for your help.